# R-module isomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, modules

If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and I be its proper ideal. Given $R$ is isomorphic to the quotient ring $R/I$ as $R$-modules . Prove that $I = 0$.
My question is - Is $R$ need to be a domain?

My solution :

let $i \in I$ and $\phi:R\to R/I$ be the isomorphism between $R$ and $R/I$ so $i\cdot\phi^{-1}(1)= \phi^{-1}(i) = \phi^{-1}(0) = 0$
and since $1 \in \phi^{-1}(1)$ implies $i= 0$ for every $i \in I$ and hence $I = 0$

Is the proof correct or missing something ? And hence is R being domain a necessity?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please you MathJax (latex) in your posts. Well, in your case you basically only need to put dollar signs around your math parts. Oh, and “element of” should be \in, not \epsilon.

Comment: The typography of your math expressions is rather confusing. You might want to edit your post with using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I reformatted your mathematical notation. Is this what you meant?
By the way: $\epsilon$ and $\in$ are distinct symbols. One is a letter, the other is not. Using one instead of the other is a bit like using $C$ instead of $\subset$.

Comment: @ Vercassivelaunos Thank you . Yes that was what i was intending to ask .

Comment: @Milten Thank you for the information . I will keep it in mind .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is right. Let $R$ be the ring of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself. Let $I$ be the ideal of functions which are $0$ everywhere apart from $1$ (so $I = \{f \in R|f(x) = 0 \textrm{ for }x \neq 1\}$). Then there is an isomorphism $\psi$  $R/I \rightarrow R$ given by $\psi(f) = f'$ where $f'(x) = f(x+1)$. Essentially $R$ is an infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, $I$ is just the first copy and once this is killed off the isomorphism $\psi$ shuffles all the remaining copies down by one coordinate. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . But is the isomorphism defined above is an R-module isomorphism ? Since for it to be true for every function f(x) in R , f(x)=f(x+1) . And for this to be true f(x) must be a constant for every x which is not the case .  Am I getting it right?

Comment: No I maybe didn't explain it very well. Think of an element of $R$ as a sequence of integers, eg. $f_1 = \{1,5,-2,0,\cdots\}$ or $f_2 = \{7,-3,0,2\cdots\}$ so for $f_2$ we have $f_2(1) = 7, f_2(2) = -3$ and so on. For example the element $f_1f_2 = \{7,-15,0,0,\cdots\}$ Then $I = \{\mathbb{Z},0,0,0,\cdots\}$ and a typical element of $R/I$ might be $f_1I = \{\mathbb{Z},5,-2,0\cdots\}$ and $\psi(f_1I) = \{5,-2,0,\cdots\}$. Then $\psi$ is an isomorphism. Checking the details might be a good way to help your understanding.
I hope this helps make things clearer.